# How to display json data in a React bootstarp card - React JS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

[image]

I am trying to display the data in card format. I am having a mock data which is array of objects. I need to display one cell of data in one single card and another cell of data in another card. But for me now all the data is getting rendered in the individual card. But I need to put one set of cell data in one card and and another set of cell data in another card. I have attached the image of the current output. I need to have (Name, RegID, and Detail in one single card) Could any one assist me what I am doing wrong. I have written the mockData and code below.

//CODE

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
const Table = ({ mockData }) => {
  function getData(cells) {
    return cells.map((cell) => {
      const { ...rest } = cell;
      console.log({ ...rest });

      const label = Object.values(rest)[2];

      const data = Object.values(rest)[3];

      console.log(data);
      return (
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <span>
              <b>{label}</b>
            </span>
            <span> {data}</span>{" "}
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      );
    });
  }
  function completeCardData(mockData) {
    return mockData.map((row) => {
      return (
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>{getData(row.cells)}</Card.Body>
        </Card>
      );
    });
  }

  return <div>{completeCardData(mockData)}</div>;
};

export default Table;
```

//Mock Data

```
[
  {
    "key": "row-0",

    "cells": [
      {
        "key": "cell-0",
        "id": "ID-0",
        "headerName": "Name",
        "CustomerName": "ABC"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-1",
        "id": "ID-1",
        "headerName": "RegID",
        "CustomerID": "P-01"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-2",
        "id": "ID-2",
        "headerName": "Detail",
        "Deatil": "Abc"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "key": "row-1",

    "cells": [
      {
        "key": "cell-1",
        "id": "ID-1",
        "headerName": "Name",
        "CustomerName": "CDE"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-2",
        "id": "ID-2",
        "headerName": "RegID",
        "CustomerID": "P-02"
      },

      {
        "key": "cell-3",
        "id": "ID-3",
        "headerName": "Detail",
        "Deatil": "CDE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use Card within map function.
Do like this:

```
 return( 
    {  mockData.map((data)=>(
    <Card>
              <Card.Body>
                <span>
                  <b>{data.cells.key}</b>
                </span>
                <span> {data.cells.CustomerName}</span>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
    )}
    )
```

Comment: I tried like that but values are coming as undefined.